# Changing number of segments on existing meshes

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

Giving a try to Blender after many years in Cinema 4D, and even so it seems nice and friendly, there are so many things that feel counter-intuitive and kind of expected and missing.
For example, help with these two uber-basic things that drive me nuts:

1. How do I change number of segments for already existing mesh, say a Sphere? I know about this floating panel at the bottom left for newly created mesh where you can define it. But once it's gone, you're done, and can't change the initial number of segments anymore?
2. For Cube I can't even see such parameter. How do I make a cube having not a single polygon per face, but let's say 2x2 polygons per face?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE! If you create a geometry via *Add > Mesh*, and define the parameters in the panel, a mesh is created with these parameters, which cannot be modified via them afterwards. Maybe you will be happy with *Geometry Nodes*. With this you can procedurally create geometries that are controllable by parameters.

Comment: Thanks! *Geometry Nodes* is another cool dimension that I haven't tried yet, but that opens up the power of Blender. something towards the direction of Houdini magic ... With my question I was looking rather for a quick start with the primitives,  which is very easy in Cinema, but I understand that I need to change my mindset from Cinema approach. Thanks again.

Comment: For the cube you can right-click and select 'Subdivide' from the popup menu. Then use the bottom-left menu if you want to increase the number of subdivisions. Should have added that this only works in Edit mode on selected faces so you need to select All first and it applies to faces on any object.

Comment: @JohnEason, thank you! That's exactly the kind of quick action to get a starting cube mesh I was looking for! .... Answered! 

Comment: And to reduce the number of faces you can select all in Edit mode and Ctrl E > Un-Subdivide. But yes, if you want to quicly change the default settings of the primitives, you need to do it right away after its creation, or use Geo Nodes instead